# Unable to backup sharded mongodb cluster: $err: "can't use 'local' database through mongos", code: 13644

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm unable to backup a sharded mongodb cluster

`/mongo-metadata/backuptest# mongodump --directoryperdb --oplog --out dump --host 10.100.x.x --port 27017
connected to: 10.100.x.x:27017
assertion: 13106 nextSafe(): { $err: "can't use 'local' database through mongos", code: 13644 }`

Anyone has a clue what is going on here?

MongoDB version: 2.6.9

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have an sharding db, and you are trying to connect on the oplog of mongos(the interface-routing of shard), but the oplog information stays at the primary data of you replica set.

Comment: This should be a comment.